# Why can my iMac see my Macbook pro with 2 different icons on the network sharing? (as if it were 2 devices)

Tags: network

I recently noticed that my iMac lists my macbook pro with 2 different icons (the normal laptop one and a generic pc one)

[image]

I am worried this means i have a server running on the background or some other possible security issue.

I disabled file sharing completely (SMB and AFP) and they both disappeared, but im still worried this might happen at some other time without my knowledge thus being a security issue.

Comment: Is it shared over AFP or SMB?

Comment: I have sharing for both enabled

Comment: then I'd guess it's finding the SMB share first, though idk why

Comment: if both sharing options are enabled, should i be seeing two different icons? or just one?

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. I only have one Mac here, the rest are PCs, so they all have that icon for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered it yourself. You had both AFP and SMB network sharing protocols enabled. Thus your mac was presented as two network devices. Notebook icon is for AFP shares and generic PC one is for SMB.

No need to worry about that since it is normal behaviour.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried replicating this (re enabled both AFP and SMB) to see if it would happen again but the iMac won't show 2 icons, just one. Any idea why?